# Flask render the same template based on two or more routes?

Tags: flask, jinja2

Say I have two different routes that share 9 items out of 10, is there a way to use the same template but have the jinja render different items based on the route it came from?

For example:

```
@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    d = {'var1': 'item1', 'var2': 'item2',}
    return render_template('myTemp.html', d=d)

@app.route('/bar')
def bar():
    d = {'var1': 'item1', 'var2': 'item2',}
    extra_variable = 'some_extra_var'
    return render_template('myTemp.html', d=d, extra_variable=extra_variable )
```

Is there a way to handle `extra_variable` on the template?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just add an `if` block to check for the variable and include any extra markup you need if it's present:

```
{% if extra_variable %}
    <p>The extra variable is... "{{ extra_variable }}".</p>
{% endif %}
```

With the template updated like so, you can then pass the extra variable to the template from the route as you have it in your question.

The markup inside the `if` block will only be displayed if the extra_variable is passed from the route. You can also nest more template logic (`if`s, `for`s, etc.) within the `if` block if you need to do something more than just show the extra variable.